# WebRequest.Create throws "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: str" exception

Tags: .net, exception, httpwebrequest

I wrote a wrapper around HttpWebRequest with the constructor :

> ```
>     public MyHttpRequest(string requestUrl)
>     {
>         this.webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
>     }
> ```

when I pass a vaild url that works in IE :

> http://www.google.co.il/search?q=%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A8+%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%9F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

I get

> System.ArgumentNullException occurred
>     Message="Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: str"
>     Source="mscorlib"
>     ParamName="str"
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.HasIllegalCharacters(String[] str)
>          at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList)
>          at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String path)
>          at System.Uri.ParseConfigFile(String file, IdnScopeFromConfig& idnStateConfig, IriParsingFromConfig& iriParsingConfig)
>          at System.Uri.GetConfig(UriIdnScope& idnScope, Boolean& iriParsing)
>          at System.Uri.InitializeUriConfig()
>          at System.Uri.InitializeUri(ParsingError err, UriKind uriKind, UriFormatException& e)
>          at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
>          at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
>          at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(String requestUriString)

Why is that ? how do i fix it ?

Comment: Which version of the .NET Framework did this occur on?

I tried it with v3.5, and it did not give me the exception.

Comment: This looks like a bug. Can you post thiss question on the Microsoft NCL support group (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/ncl)

Comment: .NET 3.5
i submitted the post to MS NCL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unescape the url, then try again.

Comment: How to escape: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519222/unescape-an-escaped-url-in-c-sharp