# Unescape an escaped url in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, url, escaping

I have urls which is escaped in this form:

```
   http://www.someurl.com/profile.php?mode=register&amp;agreed=true
```

I want to convert it to unescaped form

```
   http://www.someurl.com/profile.php?mode=register&agreed=true
```

is this the same thing as escapped html?

how do i do this?

thanks

Comment: URL encoding is completely different from HTML encoding, as this is marked duplicate of.  Flagged for reopen.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`&amp;` is an HTML entity and is used when text is encoded into HTML because you have to "escape" the `&` that has a special meaning in HTML. Apparently, this escaping mechanism was used on the URL presumably because it is used in some HTML for instance in a link. I'm not sure why you want to decode it because the browser will do the proper decoding when the link is clicked. But anyway, to revert it you can use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` in the `System.Web` namespace:

```
var encoded = "http://www.someurl.com/profile.php?mode=register&amp;agreed=true";
var decoded = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(encoded);
```

The value of `decoded` is:

```
http://www.someurl.com/profile.php?mode=register&agreed=true
```

Another form of encoding/decoding used is URL encoding. This is used to be able to include special characters in parts of the URL. For instance the characters `/`, `?` and `&` have a special meaning in a URL. If you need to include any of these characters in a say a query parameter you will have to URL encode the parameter to not mess up the URL. Here is an example of an URL where URL escaping has been used:

```
http://www.someurl.com/profile.php?company=Barnes+%26+Noble
```

The company name `Barnes & Noble` was encoded as `Barnes+%26+Noble`. If the `&` hadn't been escaped the URL would have contained not one but two query parameters because `&` is used as a delimiter between query parameters.

Comment: this is a winforms application. will it work in .net 2.0? am getting an error `HttpUtility' is not declared`

Comment: @Smith: Here is the documentation for the .NET 2.0 `HttpUtility` class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1e55w41w(v=VS.80).aspx. Did you remember to add a reference to `System.Web.dll`?

Answer (score 1):

not sure why but decode from @Martin's answer doesn't work in my case (filename in my case is "%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B6%202020%20(1)-8.xml").

For me works method - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.unescape?view=netcore-3.1 .

Be aware that this is obsolete.

Comment: You can use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.unescapedatastring instead.